# Testing hypothesis when each data instance is a vector

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova

The experiment involved studying population body velocity changes during a marathon . Velocity of each person in control group and experiment group were measured at multiple instances during marathon.

Each sample from an individual has set of velocities.

How do we infer that the  control and experiment statistically differ given the observation.

Initial thoughts

1. Take central tendency (eg : mean ) of velocity of each person in the sample and perform Mann-Whitney U Test or any suitable NHST test to verify the null hypothesis. This method greatly ignores the velocity values at specific points.
   ( ex : experiment group might have higher velocity at the beginning and reduce at the end, and still have the same mean as control group ).
2. Should we consider all the velocity points of each person for null testing 
   and perform non-parametric paired NHST test like Wilcoxons matched pair tests ? Is this way of testing appropriate for the given problem ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: This sounds like somewhere between repeated measures and time series analysis with regressors.